# Real-time data plotting via PySide

Tags: pyside

I am trying to put together a tool using python and qt gui (currently using PySide) for my experiment and I need to display data on the screen real time. Matplotlib is a little bit slow for this purpose, and I noticed that qwtplot is a perfect fit to do this task. However, I noticed that there is a way to bind qwtplot in PyQt but not in PySide... Or did I miss something that is out there?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

-Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not included in PySide but there is someone building a binding here:

https://github.com/grissiom/pysideqwt

On a side note, it's usually possible to switch from pyside to pyqt with little to no changes to the code.

Comment: Do you know of any other binding libraries? I'm actually in the same situation, need a qwt binding for Pyside. PySide is an LGPL license while PyQT isn't

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider another plotting library, [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/), which supports both PySide and PyQt and looks very fast (only used it a little bit myself so far, but I've been impressed with what I've seen)